# Question about integration on a box

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Let $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and $f: Q \to \mathbb{R} $ is integrable over $Q$. $f \geq 0$. if $A \subseteq Q$, then $\int_Q f \geq \int_A f $

Attempt: say $\epsilon > 0$

Let $P_1$ be a partition of $A$ and $P_2$ be a partition of $Q$. Say $\tilde{Q}_i $ is a subrectangle of the partition $P_1$ and $Q_i$ is a subrectangle of $P_2$. Then, obviously we have $ \sup_{x \in \tilde{Q}_i } f(x) \leq \sup_{x \in Q_i } f(x) $. So, we must have $U(f,P_1) \leq U(f,P_2 ) $. Similarly, $L(f,P_2) \leq L(f,P_1)$. So,

$$ U(f,P_1) - L(f,P_1) \leq U(f,P_2) - L(f,P_2) < \epsilon $$

So $f$ is integrable in $A$. In particular since $U(f,P_1) \leq U(f,P_2)$, if we take inf over all partitions, we obtain:

$$ \inf_{\mathcal{P}} U(f,P_1) \leq \inf_{\mathcal{P}} U(f,P_2) \implies \int_A f \leq \int_Q f $$

Is this correct? thanks for any feedback/suggestion

Comment: This looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it looks fine.

Just mention $U$ is upper sum and $L$ is lower sum.